# Django RF 405 error for POST request on APIView without ending slash

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, request

I'm pretty new to Django Rest Framework and I've been investigating this issue but can't find any solution. I'm pretty sure it will be a small detail but I'm out of idea.

I'm using DRF for a project. The team made the choice to not end URL paths with a ' / '. I have an endpoint linked to an APIView with a POST method. We want to do some stuff with a body sent in this POST. However calling it brings (Postman response):

*405 Method Not allowed*

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
}
```

Putting a ' / ' at the end of the URL path works (Postman response for normal behavior):

```
{
    "success": True,
    "message": "A message returned by the function in APIView"
}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from runbook import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)

router.register(r'my_objects', views.ObjectViewset)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('my_objects/myFunction',
         views.MyFunctionView.as_view(),
         name="my-function")
```

**views.py**

```
class MyFunctionView(APIView):
    """
    """
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            MyObject.objects.get(slug=slugify(request.data['candidate_name']))
        except MyObject.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(boolean_response(False))
        else:
            return Response(boolean_response(True))
```

**What I read and tried**:

1. Wrong type of view: [405 "Method POST is not allowed" in Django REST framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011333/405-method-post-is-not-allowed-in-django-rest-framework) ; [405 “Method POST is not allowed” in Django REST framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588539/405-method-post-is-not-allowed-in-django-rest-framework)
2. Use of slashes: [405 POST method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983222/405-post-method-not-allowed) ; [How can I make a trailing slash optional on a Django Rest Framework SimpleRouter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163838/how-can-i-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-on-a-django-rest-framework-simplerouter)
3. Potential indentation problem: [django rest framework post method giving error "Method "POST" not allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178759/django-rest-framework-post-method-giving-error-method-post-not-allowed)
4. Permissions: https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53705361.shtml
5. APPEND_SLASH in settings.py: [DRF post url without end slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356900/drf-post-url-without-end-slash) ; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#append-slash

I also tried to:

- Call with a '/' at the end even though the urls.py doesn't have one (new error: *404 Not found* because URL is not the same)
- Test in terminal instead of Postman (same errors)

Is it possible to make this request without '/'? Am I using Django tools wrong? Is there any subtlety I am not seeing ?
So if anyone has a solution, advice or idea. Thank you !

Comment: The `DefaultRouter` is creating some URL patterns for `ObjectViewset` class which are conflicting with `my_objects/myFunction` path

Comment: @ArakkalAbu you are right. I tested and indeed the router takes the priority and Django never "reach" the other pattern. I just learn that the order is important in ```urlpatterns``` thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as said by @Arakkal Abu in the comment the router conflict with the other path in urlpatterns

Solution: send the router include at the end of the urlpatterns

```
router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)

router.register(r'my_objects', views.ObjectViewset)
urlpatterns = [
path('my_objects/myFunction',
     views.MyFunctionView.as_view(),
     name="my-function"),
path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

Indeed *my_objects/myFunction* is considered as part of the route *my_objects/* where *my_objects/myFunction/* is considered as a separate route and that's why it was working.